# Does UML allow a connection (delegation) between ports and activity parameters?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I found an example UML diagram which puzzles me:

[image]

I am not sure if this corresponds to UML 2.4.1 as no modeling tool I tried lets me create the connection. I looked up the specification and I think that the connection is not valid UML 2.4.1 because an activity parameter node is not a ConnectableElement, but I am not sure. However, the example is taken from the specification of the UML MARTE 1.1 profile by the OMG, which says

> Note that this usage of connectors is
>   compatible with the abstract syntax of UML, as both Property and Parameter are ConnectableElements

In the above figure, `input` is of type `Activity Parameter Node` which is special type of `ObjectNode`, similar but different to `Pin`. It is associate with parameters owned by the activity:

[image]

The connection in the figure is a delegation connector. As can be seen in the above hierarchy, ActivityParameterNode is not a ConnectableElement, so I think the statement in the UML MARTE specification is wrong.

Is this connection is valid UML 2.4.1 and should be supported by UML modelling tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no valid UML (neither 2.4.1 nor 2.5 or any prior one). It mixes behavior with static design. A port on a class is a static construct which allows to attach interfaces. An `ActivityParameterNode` in contrast is used to model "data flow" (it can send or receive objects via an `ObjectFlow` to/from `Pin`s of `Action`s inside).

This is (probably; my knowledge is not sufficient here) valid in MARTE. You can make it valid in your domain by introducing a profile which defines this language construct. Most likely you could use a MARTE profile for UML or an extension of it or (as said) you make your own.

P.S.: I tried that in Enterprise Architect and it lets create me a `Dependency` or an `InformationFlow` between both.

Comment: I don't know if the reason that it is not valid is that it mixes structure and behavior, although I agree that this is the gist of UML. The UML 2.4.1. spec says "However, it does not preclude mixing different kinds of diagram types, as one might do when one combines structural and behavioral elements (e.g., showing a state machine nested inside an internal structure). Consequently, the boundaries between the various kinds of diagram types are not strictly enforced." The parameter node is also not an activity pin, but it is not a ConnectableElement.

Comment: Mixing elements in diagrams is valid. You can put (almost) any element in any diagram as Annex A states. However, the above has nothing to do with diagrams. It's a structural issue. UML explicitly states which connectors are allowed between which elements and what their semantic is. What else if not a `Pin` is that rectangle labeled "Input"?

Comment: Also, since connectors are doomed to be more simplistic than classes, what kind of connector is the one between `Port` and `Pin`?

Comment: It's an Activity Parameter Node (generalizes ObjectNode in the same way as Pin) which has an association to Parameter object of the containing Activity. But still this doesn't change much since a Paramter is not a ConnectableElement. The spec says it's a delegation connector.

Comment: I've added a picture of the definition of ActivityNodeParameter to the question to show the type of this. I think the statement from the MARTE spec is wrong.

Comment: Ah, sure. You got me on the wrong foot. Pins are on Actions and ActivityParameterNodes are on Activities. Alas, the connection to a Port is still invalid. What the mean with "compatible" is that you can attach connectors to both. But (as said) UML also limits the possible connector types.